# How set root view dynamically in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, dart-pub

devs

I have a situation where I want to change my root view based on condition. For example, if a user is logged in already then root view will be Home screen else login screen.

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main.dart File you have the function `void main() => runApp(MyApp());` where MyApp is a widget returing a MaterialApp widget or something similar. You can already select here to start with a different `home` widget.

If you have to select the start screen based on some asynchronous operation (like checking settings in Preferences or Secure Storage), you return a FutureBuilder instead of your MaterialApp. The FutureBuilder then returns the widget after finishing the operation.